# Assign / Add Content Item To ListPart Orchard Core Programmatically

Tags: c#, .net-core, orchardcms, orchard-modules, orchardcore

I have an API to create contentItem, but how can i assign it to other content's ListPart ?
for example i have a Audio Album that has a ListPart with content type Audio Item.

currently i'm using content manager

```
 var contentItem = await _contentManager.NewAsync("AudioItem");

 await _contentManager.CreateAsync(contentItem, VersionOptions.DraftRequired);

 contentItem.DisplayText = name;

 await _contentManager.UpdateAsync(contentItem);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Weld` and `Alter` extensions to modify a content item.

```
contentItem.Weld<ContainedPart>();
contentItem.Alter<ContainedPart>(x => x.ListContentItemId  = "id-of-parent");
```

`Weld` will add the `ContainedPart`, and `Alter` will changes it's value.